# Microsoft HPC parametric sweep job run time differs between Windows versions

Tags: windows, cluster-computing, hpc

I have an HPC cluster consisting of head node and two compute nodes with same hardware, but different Windows version: one is running Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2, and the other one Microsoft Windows Server 2019.

HPC pack 2012 is installed on all nodes.

I am running a parametric sweep job consisting of 300 tasks, on a single node each time (taking the other node to offline), and getting significant difference in the total job run time: 14 seconds on Win 2012 node, 57 seconds on Win 2019 node.

I have examined the job’s individual tasks run times. On Win 2012 all tasks have similar short run times (<1 second). On Win 2019 the first batch of tasks has significantly longer run times relative to other tasks: first 28 tasks run time is 45 seconds, while the rest 272 tasks are fast as on the other node. 28 is also a number of the subscribed cores of this node – probably related.

I have examined the HPC logs, as advised here: https://github.com/Azure/hpcpack/blob/master/kb/000000_How%20to%20collect%20HPC%20Pack%20logs.md.

I don’t see errors or exceptions, but I do see a difference in HpcNodeManager logs the beginning of the run.

**Win 2012:**

HpcNodeManager      Creating job entry for job ID 26821, user ***

HpcNodeManager      Start Task JobId 26821, TaskId 307471.

HpcNodeManager      Creating process for JobId 26821, TaskId 307471 with the command line C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /S /c ***\Job0026821.cmd 1

…

(log continues with the rest of the tasks)

**Win 2019:**

HpcNodeManager      Creating job entry for job ID 26822, user ***

HpcNodeManager      Start Task JobId 26822, TaskId 307772.

HpcNodeManager      Time to create Job Id 26822 : 566 milliseconds.

HpcNodeManager      Sharing existing JobEntry

HpcNodeManager      Time to create Job Id 26822 : 566 milliseconds.

HpcNodeManager      Sharing existing JobEntry

…

(the previous two lines are repeated, total of 27 times)

…

HpcNodeManager      Creating process for JobId 26822, TaskId 307772 with the command line C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /S /c ***\Job0026822.cmd 1
…
(log continues with the rest of the tasks)

**Why is the first batch of tasks is so slow to initialize on Win 2019? What may cause the difference to Win 2012?**